# javap says there is a main method, java says I'm insane

Tags: java

I have some class files from a .jar file. I am looking for a class with a Main method, so I can see how this program works without its web baggage.

```
>javap HaploGrepServer/HaploGrepMain
Compiled from "HaploGrepMain.java"
public class HaploGrepServer.HaploGrepMain extends java.lang.Object{
    public HaploGrepServer.HaploGrepMain();
    public static void main(java.lang.String[])       throws java.io.IOException;
}
```

Great! I've found it

```
>java HaploGrepServer/HaploGrepMain
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/restlet/Component
    at java.lang.ClassLoader....
```

OK I can add that

```
>java -cp org.restlet.jar HaploGrepServer/HaploGrepMain
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HaploGrepServer/HaploGrepMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HaploGrepServer.HaploGrepMain
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: HaploGrepServer/HaploGrepMain. Program will exit.
```

what gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're invoking a class within a package, try using dots to separate the package components, not slashes:

```
java -cp .:org.restlet.jar HaploGrepServer.HaploGrepMain
```

Comment: that's good idea but it doesn't fix the error:

`java -cp org.restlet.jar HaploGrepServer.HaploGrepMain 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HaploGrepServer/HaploGrepMain
`

Answer (score 1):

If the `HaploGrepServer` is in the current directory, you need to include the current directory in the classpath with `.`:

```
java -cp .:org.restlet.jar HaploGrepServer.HaploGrepMain
```

Answer (score 1):

The command:

```
    java HaploGrepServer.HaploGrepMain
```

uses the default class path of '`.`'. When you supply a classpath with:

```
    java -cp restlet.jar HaploGrepServer.HaploGrepMain
```

the class path now *only* contains the restlet jar.

So, you need the class path to include both locations:

```
   java -cp restlet.jar:. HaploGrepServer.HaploGrepMain
```

Note: if you are on a Windows platform, use a semicolon to instead of a colon.